# How to read data from xml file in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have below xml file data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<rootnode>
  <TExportCarcass>
    <BodyNum>6168</BodyNum>
    <BodyWeight>331.40</BodyWeight>
    <UnitID>1</UnitID>
    <Plant>239</Plant>
    <pieces>
      <TExportCarcassPiece index="0">
        <Bruising>0</Bruising>
        <RFIDPlant></RFIDPlant>
      </TExportCarcassPiece>
      <TExportCarcassPiece index="1">
        <Bruising>0</Bruising>
        <RFIDPlant></RFIDPlant>
      </TExportCarcassPiece>
    </pieces>
  </TExportCarcass>
  <TExportCarcass>
    <BodyNum>6169</BodyNum>
    <BodyWeight>334.40</BodyWeight>
    <UnitID>1</UnitID>
    <Plant>278</Plant>
    <pieces>
      <TExportCarcassPiece index="0">
        <Bruising>0</Bruising>
        <RFIDPlant></RFIDPlant>
      </TExportCarcassPiece>
      <TExportCarcassPiece index="1">
        <Bruising>0</Bruising>
        <RFIDPlant></RFIDPlant>
      </TExportCarcassPiece>
    </pieces>
  </TExportCarcass>
</rootnode>
```

I am using python's `lxml` module to read data from xml file like below:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('file.xml')

memoryElem = doc.find('BodyNum')
print(memoryElem)
```

But its only printing `None` instead of `6168`. Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate each `TExportCarcass` tag and then use `find` to access `BodyNum`

**Ex:**

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('file.xml')
for elem in doc.findall('TExportCarcass'):
    print(elem.find("BodyNum").text)
```

**Output:**

```
6168
6169
```

---

or

```
print([i.text for i in doc.findall('TExportCarcass/BodyNum')]) #-->['6168', '6169']
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run `find` on a text string, it will only search for elements at the root level. You can instead use `xpath` queries within `find` to search for any element within the doc:

1. To get the first element only:

```py
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse('file.xml')

memoryElem = doc.find('.//BodyNum')
memoryElem.text
# 6168
```

2. To get all elements:

```py
[ b.text for b in doc.iterfind('.//BodyNum') ]
# ['6168', '6169']
```

Answer (score 2):

1 - Use `/` to specify the tree level of the element you want to extract

2 - Use `.text` to extract the name of the elemnt

```
doc = etree.parse('file.xml')
memoryElem = doc.find("*/BodyNum") #BodyNum is one level down
print(memoryElem.text)  #Specify you want to extract the name of the element
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the inbuild `xml.etree.Etree` module of python

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0):

Your document contains multiple `BodyNum` elements.
You need to put an explicit limit into a query if you need only the 1st element.

Use the following flexible approach based on `xpath` query:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('file.xml')
memoryElem = doc.xpath('(//BodyNum)[1]/text()')
print(memoryElem)   # ['6168']
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the number of `TExportCarcass`

Comment: Sure thanks, I thought we can use comment section to ask for extra information.

Comment: @SAndrew, Are you sure that this approach worth to be silly downvoted?

Comment: This is also a valid answer. Not sure why it was downvoted